# How to search by an object in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In springboot you can have a repository that `extends JpaRepository<User, String>`

Now if you want to write a query to that repository, you can write multiple findBy queries such as:

```
User findByUsername(String username);
User findByFirstName(String firstName);
User findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
```

then you need matching controllers like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<User> getUser(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
    return userService.findByUsername(username);
}
```

etc, etc...

I don't want to have to write every single findBy for each combination of elements and create all the matching controllers like that.

So what I want to know is how you can search by a whole object. For example posting something like

```
{
"username":"freddy"
}
```

will search by username and equally

```
{
"firstName":"Fred",
"lastName":"Doe"
}
```

will search by first and last name.

Is there a way to write both a JpaRepository method and a controller that can take a (in this case) User object with any combination of fields, and perform a search for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try JPA's **Query by Example**. `JpaRepository` extends another interface named `QueryByExampleExecutor`, which has a quite a few methods for searching by example. Here is a simple example,

```
// here the first name, last name, and username may be null 
// or not null. Make sure that they are not all at the same time
String firstName = "James";
String lastName = null;
String userName = "jbond";

Example<User> example = Example.of(new User(firstName, lastName, username));
Iterable<User> = repository.findAll(example);
```

You can do other fancy stuff. Here is an [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/query-by-example).

> Q. Is there a way to return unique result fields? So in that example, passing firstName would return a unique list of all the lastNames and all the possible userNames

For this type of situations, I haved used native queries. Here is an example,

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT u.lastName FROM User u WHERE u.firstName = ?1", 
       nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findDistinctLastName(String firstName);
```

Comment: Is there a way to return unique result fields? So in that example, passing firstName would return a unique list of all the lastNames and all the possible userNames